# How to not be asked for a password when modifying system files?

Tags: authentication, administrator

I constantly tinker with my system files and other whatnot, and it's a pain to literally type in a password every single time I edit a system file. I am the only user on my computer. Any way to do this?

Comment: Set perms for the enclosing folder & contents to include yourself(Me) as 'Read & Write' from Cmd/i Get Info

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do so. You can either execute `sudo su` or `sudo -i`. This requires password once. Then you can issue any command without need of sudo (including modifying files). Or you can set a directory or file's permissions or owner by:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /directory/file.txt
```

This sets the permissions to read, write execute on the owning user, group and others.

```
sudo chown -R username:users /directory/file.txt
```

You can make chown groups also. I am not sure how but the `groupadd` command is involved